# how to add values of textshadow in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow

I really want long shadows in Javascript but I dont want to code every single one line of them ,so i thought automize it so it works something like this :

```
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
  document.getElementById("text").style.textShadow = i + "px" + ' ' + i + "px" + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + color
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work. I also tried it with arrays with no luck, the only real working thing is to code every single one of the shadows, but I want an adaptable solution.
How can I try and implement it?

Comment: This is solvable using only CSS. Is there are reason why you're using JS?

Comment: you are only updating one component (the one with id "text"), and setting it's shadow to something like: `10px 10px 0 #000`. That third value (0) is the blur of the shadow, at zero you won't have a shadow. Also I'm not sure why you bind the x/y offsets to `i` but I guess you have a reason :)

Comment: Why don't you add the shadow to the class `text`  in CSS and if you want to control when the shadow is "on" you can add or remove the class via JS

Comment: @pretzelhammer im using JS because i like JS but if css only works i guess i'll give it a try but thanks to all fast answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use an array here to add all shadow variables and then join them as a comma-separated string to get the desired output like:

```js
const color = '#696767';
let shadow = []

for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  shadow.push(i + "px" + ' ' + i + "px" + ' 0 ' + color)
}

document.getElementById("text").style.textShadow = shadow.join(',')
```

```css
#text {
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top:0
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text"> HELLO WORLD </h1>
```